# Как переместить строку поиска вверх?

Tags: html

Есть большое расширение на JS, в которое я пытаюсь вставить поиск по странице. Проблема в том, что никак не получается разместить строку поиска где нибудь сверху. Вот HTML составляющая расширения:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="auto">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Genius</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://local_resource_host/css/glue.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lyrics.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" class="userCSS" href="https://zlink.app.spotify.com/css/user.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="glue-page-header__background-scroll-overlay"></div>
    <div class="navbar sticky-top" data-sticky="true">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav " data-navbar="navbar" data-navbar-history-position="" style="visibility: visible;">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lyrics-versions-container">
        <div id="lyrics-versions"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="lyrics-lines-container" class="lyrics-lines-container"></div>
    <div id="message-container" class="message-container hidden"></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <!-- "init.js" is served by the desktop client and provides the "window.__spotify" object. -->
    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="lyrics.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В него я пытаюсь вставить кусок кода, который будет производить поиск по странице

HTML:

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id="text-to-find" value=""> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: FindOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;" value="Искать"/>
<br/><i>Введите слово или фразу для поиска.</i>
<hr/>
</body>
```

Вот как я попробовал, и как это выглядит:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="auto">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Genius</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://local_resource_host/css/glue.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lyrics.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" class="userCSS" href="https://zlink.app.spotify.com/css/user.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="glue-page-header__background-scroll-overlay"></div>
    <div class="navbar sticky-top" data-sticky="true">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav " data-navbar="navbar" data-navbar-history-position="" style="visibility: visible;">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lyrics-versions-container">
        <div id="lyrics-versions"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="lyrics-lines-container" class="lyrics-lines-container"></div>
    <div id="message-container" class="message-container hidden"></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <!-- "init.js" is served by the desktop client and provides the "window.__spotify" object. -->
    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="lyrics.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
<body>
<input type="text" id="text-to-find" value=""> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: FindOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;" value="Искать"/>
<br/><i>Введите слово или фразу для поиска.</i>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не устраивает, строка поиска внизу, нужно, что бы она была сверху.

Пробовал ещё поместить в head, но там строка вообще уползает вверх, что её даже не видно.

В общем, подскажите пожалуйста, куда этот кусок воткнуть

Comment: Вставляйте без тегов <body> и </body>. И вставляйте хотя бы примерно по коду, а то вниз вставляете, и хотите, чтобы вверху было

Comment: Да, получилось. Вставил в середину body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось, вставив в середину body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="auto">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Genius</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://local_resource_host/css/glue.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lyrics.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" class="userCSS" href="https://zlink.app.spotify.com/css/user.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="glue-page-header__background-scroll-overlay"></div>
    <div class="navbar sticky-top" data-sticky="true">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav " data-navbar="navbar" data-navbar-history-position="" style="visibility: visible;">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lyrics-versions-container">
        <div id="lyrics-versions"></div>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="text-to-find" value=""> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: FindOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;" value="Искать"/>
<br/><i>Введите слово или фразу для поиска.</i>
<hr/>
    <div id="lyrics-lines-container" class="lyrics-lines-container"></div>
    <div id="message-container" class="message-container hidden"></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <!-- "init.js" is served by the desktop client and provides the "window.__spotify" object. -->
    <script src="init.js"></script>
    <script src="lyrics.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```